# What is framework means?

Tags: frameworks, cucumber

I am new to IT field. I am learning Ruby cucumber for testing. Can anyone explain what is framework means? Why cucumber is called a frame work? What exactly the framework will do?
Please expalin me in layman terms...

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Software_framework

Comment: Check out this article:
http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/5381/What-Is-A-Framework

Answer (score 1):

In simple word

> A framework is like helping Tool for software development. it will
>   make your development process faster, add new functionality

and also you can use ready-made code or functionality. so, you will not have to code everything from scratch.

ex: If you want to make 500 Paper plane then if you measure and cut every piece of paper individually then it will consume more time. but if you use first cut paper and cut bunch of paper using that first piece, it will be less time consuming.  i hope you understand.

> "Framework is pre-built functionality that you can directly use in
>   your project. to make development process faster."

Answer (score 0):

a framework is an  “Inversion of Control”. If you know what library is then framework is a library that calls your code instead of you calling the library and getting data , a framework as a library makes a call-back to your code.